# Is there a way to assign columns from a file to multiple arrays?

Tags: perl

I have a file named data.txt that looks like this:

```
12487 72 3.179
12487 84 2.47
12976 82 3.22
12443 81 4.29
```

What I need to be able to do is place each column in its own array when it is read from the file so it would be like this:

```
@a = 12487 12487 12976 12443
@b = 72 84 82 81
@c = 3.179 2.47 3.22 4.29
```

So each line would do something like $1 goes into @a $2 goes into @b $3 goes into @c - But I'm not sure how to exactly do this.

I've started by trying to grab each array index from each line, but this is too much to sort through (the file is quite large). I'm pretty new to perl so I'm pretty confused and am not sure what I should be looking for in the perldoc (which is what I'm using as a reference to get started).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [push](http://p3rl.org/push) to append an element to an array.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my (@a, @b, @c);
while (<>) {
    my @columns = split;
    push @a, $columns[0];
    push @b, $columns[1];
    push @c, $columns[2];
}

say "@$_" for \@a, \@b, \@c;
```

Instead of the three pushes, you can use

```
    push @{ (\@a, \@b, \@c)[$_] }, $columns[$_] for 0 .. 2;
```

but I don't find it readable. It iterates over the columns and the arrays to append to at the same time.

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I needed to find!

Comment: Might be slightly more readible:  `($a[$.-1],$b[$.-1],$c[$.-1])=split;`   ... but some other use of `$.` might be yet more readable.